# RAM de-fragmentation from command prompt

Tags: matlab, cmd

Can I de-fragment RAM from cmd? or matlab

I know that `pack` command de-fragment RAM in matlab. but it should run from command window. I want something callable from scripts or functions

Answer (score 0):

FAST Defrag from AMS has command-line support. I did only use the GUI so far, but it might be worth a try... 
http://www.amsn.ro/index.php?action=2